# How to allow two different ASP.NET sessions in the same domain name/ ip address?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

so I am building two different apps using MVC 4 and MVC 5 frameworks. They both are hosted under the same ip address.

Both of them are fighting for the cookie session (called by default .ASPXAUTH). So if I login on app1, app2 will sign out and viceversa.

I tried customizing the cookie name on the Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" defaultUrl="~/Service/Index" name=".ASPXAUTH_Mobile" timeout="5" protection="All" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

Which actually changed the cookie name on the app1, but it still got overriden by the cookie on app2 as soon as I sign onto the app2.

Any suggestions on getting both apps sessions to work at the same time?

Comment: Same IPAddress and port? If yes, you can add an entry in etc/hosts file to identify the apps as different website names. You will have to change the bindings to reflect correct name too.

Comment: Same IPAddress, different port (8099 vs default 80). Is there any more code-encapsulated solution?

Comment: what code used to generate formsauthentication cookie? have you tried changing cookie path to app1 and app2 yet?

Comment: It is autogenerated using the config presented on the question. What do you mean by pTh? Thanks!

Comment: 2018 I have the same Issue is there any fix?